# Display inherited methods and properties in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Are there any options or plugins that display inherited members (methods/properties) inline when editing a class file in Visual Studio?  The inherited code would probably be disabled/grayed out, but it seems like it could be useful and interesting to have the option to view an entire composed class at once.

Comment: Sounds like you want something that modifies intellisense to be more 'intelligent'?

Comment: No, I'm more interested in actually visualizing the inherited code together with my subclass code.

Answer (score 0):

Ahha, I remember what I was thinking of now. Take a look at [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).

[Example](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html#Code_Completion):

[image]
<sub>(source: [jetbrains.com](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/screenshots/40/code_completion_type_C.png))</sub>

Comment: Hmm, maybe this isn't what you need. I can't seem to find an example on their website.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to see only available properties/methods, not their inner code:

To see all properties, you can just press Ctrl+Space inside any method, and filter results depending on what you need. On screenshot only Properties are displayed - bold are class's own properties, and normal are inherited.
[image: Class properties]